# Does Application Insights work with CoreCLR?

Tags: azure-application-insights, coreclr

I recently deployed a CoreCLR application to Azure and I clicked the button to "Enable Application Insights monitoring".  Azure web UI now shows "Application insights extension is already installed" for my application.  However, no data is showing up.  The primary suspect of course is the fact that I am using `coreclr`.

So the question is, does the Application Insights Extension work with `coreclr` apps?  It is an API App built on MVC if that matters.

`global.json:`

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
    "runtime": "coreclr"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect that Web App Extension will work for Core CLR project, there is a [separate AI nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet/) to instrument the project in the development time.
The instructions for AI in ASP.NET core projects are on [GitHub here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started).